# Python filename regular expression extract

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I'm trying to copy paste a file from a folder to folder. However this file is produced everyday, so the filename changes. I'd like create a reg expression that would identify the correct file in the folder. I'm not familiar with regex so maybe I could get some tips?

The file path for the copied file is the following:
    G:\ Trade Reports_Daily1_FI_2000_2018-07-24-06-40-42.xlsx

This part is the same in all the files.

Trade Reports_Daily
This part changes.

```
2018-07-24-06-40-42.xlsx
```

I figured I might use the datetime module to help with the right date. However the numbers after the date (-06-40-42) are random.

```
import re, os

from datetime import date
today = date.today()

RNRegex = re.compile(r'Rolfe and Nolan Trade Reports_Daily1_FI_2000_' + str(today) +'-\d\d-\d\d-\d\d.xlsx')
#os.listdir(r'G:RLN FI Reports')

for RNfile in os.listdir(r'G:\RLN FI Reports'):
    mo = RNRegex.search(RNfile)

    if mo == None:
        continue
    else:
        print(mo)

EDIT:
My Output now

runfile('C:/Users/z000xxx/.spyder-py3/untitled21.py', 
wdir='C:/Users/z000xxc/.spyder-py3')
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 69), match='Rolfe and Nolan Trade 
Reports_Daily1_FI_2000_2018>
```

Comment: Do not use upper case naming for variables in Python! Do not use spaces in Windows paths!

Comment: This works for me `RNRegex = re.compile(r'Rolfe and Nolan Trade Reports_Daily1_FI_2000_' + str(today) +'-\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}.xlsx')`

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. If you believe your question is not useful or is no longer useful, it should be deleted instead of editing out all of the data that actually makes it a question. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the CC BY-SA 3.0 license). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
 today = date.strftime(date.today(), "%Y-%m-%d")

 RNRegex = re.compile("Rolfe and Nolan Trade Reports_Daily1_FI_2000_" + today + "(-\d{2}){3}\.xlsx")
```

On a side note, if you want to get the file name you cannot print the result of a `search`, you will need to use `print(mo.group(0))`

I had to use `date.strftime`  to format the `date.today` for it to not print months and days as single digits sometimes

EDIT: Only match today file

Comment: Don't escape `_`, they are word chars (matched with `\w`), so not special for the regex engine.

Comment: oh, maybe I didnt understood well what you were asking, do you want to get ONLY the file with today's date ?

Answer (score -1):

You could simply list what's on the folder and move the files starting with 'Rolfe and Nolan Trade Reports_Daily', without using any regex. Would look something like this:

```
import os
files = os.listdir('G:\RLN FI Reports')
for f in files:
    if f.startswith('Rolfe and Nolan Trade Reports_Daily'):
        # move the file wherever you want
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also use `glob.glob('G:\Path\To\Files\Keywords_*.ext')`. This behaves like the Windows Command `dir` with the asterisk as greedy character.

**Example: Glob**

```
>> import glob
>> glob.glob('C:\Windows\*.dll')
['C:\\Windows\\EvtMessage.dll',
 'C:\\Windows\\RtlExUpd.dll',
 'C:\\Windows\\twain.dll',
 'C:\\Windows\\twain_32.dll']
```

**Example: Window Command**

```
C:\>dir /B C:\Windows\*.dll
EvtMessage.dll
RtlExUpd.dll
twain.dll
twain_32.dll
```

---

In this example I did not use a keyword in the file name. You might want to use `Rolfe and Nolan Trade Reports_Daily1_FI_2000_`.

Comment: @LoveisHell `import time`; `import os`; `os.mkdir('SAP{}'.format(time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d', time.gmtime()))`